# Using matplotlib to graph rows by column of a csv file

Tags: python, file, csv, matplotlib, plot

Very new at Python and first time using matplotlib

I'm trying to graph a multiline plot based on the rows of a CSV file.

CSV file looks something like this:

```
Row1        S1      S2     S3      HWS
Row2        2.45    3.76   2.44    1
Row3        3.59    2.56   9.68    2
Row4        2.54    9.45   6.78    3
```

I want to graph the HWS values by each row in the csv file.

Ex: For Row2, I want my points to be (1, 2.45), (2, 3.76), and (3, 2.44).
For Row3, I want my points to be (1, 3.59), (2, 2.56), and (3, 9.68).

I've already looked at modules like pandas from other stack overflow answers, but I can't find commands to graph by rows. All I found is ways to graph a whole CSV file or ways to isolate columns of a csv file.

Is there a way to graph this way using Python and matplotlib?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read in each column in the csv into separate lists.

plotting the data is trivial. Here's a basic example in your code the data sets come from the csv.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

s1 = [2,3,2]
s2 = [3,2,9]
s3 = [2,9,6]
hws = [1,2,3]

plt.plot(hws,s1)
plt.plot(hws,s2)
plt.plot(hws,s3)
```

Comment: I have a huge dataset - is there a way for me to read the specific columns s1, s2, s3... I can't manually type them. Thanks!

Comment: yes there most certainly is. At this point in the discussion, referencing the teach a man to fish etc, you'll find it beneficial to try googling "how to read a csv with python". In fact this question could have found a solution using this method as well. Best of luck to you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you have a huge dataset.!

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

os.chdir(r"C:\--")  #path of your csv file

S1=[]
S2=[]
S3=[]
HWS=[]
with open('dataSet.csv','r') as csvFile:
    reader=csv.reader(csvFile,delimiter=';')
    next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        temp=row[0]
        S1.append(temp)
        temp=row[1]
        S2.append(temp)
        temp=row[2]
        S3.append(temp)
        temp=row[3]
        HWS.append(temp)
plt.plot(HWS,S1)
plt.plot(HWS,S2)
plt.plot(HWS,S3)
plt.show()
```

Comment: This solution looks great - but I get an error when I try to run it: IndexError: list index out of range

i know it probably doesn't have to do with the code, but if you know, could you shed some light as to why this error is happening?

Comment: which version of python you are using.?
try changing delimiter to ',', try 'rb' at the place of 'r' in 9th line and keep r before the path of your file in line 4

Comment: I'm using python 2.7.10

Comment: i am using 3, anyways try 'rb' at the place of 'r'.

Comment: still no luck...the error only appears when I add the code past "temp=row[0]
 S1.append(temp)"

Comment: keeping everything the same but changing delimiter to ',' from ';' works for me.

Comment: changing the delimiter to ',' worked great -- however, if i have a huge dataset with thousands of rows, I need to somehow automate the append() command. Do you know how to do that? Sorry for all the questions, I'm a novice programmer.

Comment: if you have thousands of row but four columns, there's no need to automate. But if the number of columns are significant you could either use a multidimensional array or another for loop within the existing one...GoodLuck.!